# Всплывающее уведомление Android

Tags: java, android

Может вопрос банален и где-то его решение есть, но удовлетворяющего ответа я, к сожалению, найти не смог.

Как сделать всплывающее уведомление? У меня получилось только сделать так, чтобы оно просто приходило и было в самом низу списка уведомлений. Что нужно добавить в код?

```
Notification.Builder builder =
            new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_help)
            .setContentTitle("Напоминание")
            .setSubText("База вопросов").setStyle(new Notification.BigTextStyle().bigText("Новый вопрос!"));

        Notification notification = builder.build();

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
```

Comment: попробуйте добавить приоритет `builder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)`, пока больше ничего не вспомнил

Comment: Уже так делал, не помогло

Comment: Тыщу лет не запускал студию на домашнем компе, но попробую протестить. Доп. вопрос - а есть другие уведомления в шторке? Если да, то какие и сколько?

Answer (score 3):

У меня некий конечный рабочий вариант получился таким:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    companion object {
        const val channelId = "just_random_string_395"
        const val notifyId = 395
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        sendNotification()
    }

    private fun sendNotification() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) createChannel()
        val notification = buildNotification()
        val manager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        manager.cancel(notifyId)
        manager.notify(notifyId, notification)
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private fun createChannel() {
        val manager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        val name = "Notification channel name"
        val channel = NotificationChannel(channelId, name, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
        channel.description = "Notification channel description"
        manager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }

    private fun buildNotification(): Notification {
        val builder = notificationBuilder
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
            .setContentTitle("Заголовок")
            .setSubText("Описание сути уведомления")
            .setStyle(NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText("Очень длинный текст...\nРеально очень длинный. \n Целых три строчки!"))
            .priority = NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX
        return builder.build()
    }

    private val notificationBuilder
        get() = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
        else NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
}
```

Это стандартная активность в пустом приложении. Лишнего кода тут, вроде бы, нет.

Ваша ошибка, как я могу предположить, в том, что Вы не используете каналы уведомлений.

Надеюсь, это поможет.

**Update**
Версия кода для тех, кто использует Java:

```
public class MainActivityJava extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String channelId = "just_random_string_395";
    private static final int notifyId = 395;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        sendNotification();
    }

    private void sendNotification() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) createChannel();
        Notification notification = buildNotification();
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        if (manager != null) {
            manager.cancel(notifyId);
            manager.notify(notifyId, notification);
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private void createChannel() {
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        String name = "Notification channel name";
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, name, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        channel.setDescription("Notification channel description");
        if (manager != null)
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }

    private Notification buildNotification() {
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = notificationBuilder();
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
                .setContentTitle("Заголовок")
                .setSubText("Описание сути уведомления")
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText("Очень длинный текст...\nРеально очень длинный. \n Целых три строчки!"))
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX);
        return builder.build();
    }

    private NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
            return new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId);
        else return new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId);
    }
}
```